# Is there way to notify by email when word file is opened

Tags: vba, security, ms-word, ms-office

I want to know when and possibly where my .doc file is opened. If document is copied from my PC and opened on another PC I want to email me on which PC document is opened.

Comment: You realize that it can be opened on a device without internet, right? I think that the only way to do that is to install on the target computer additional program, that will monitor the file and as soon as it is opened it will mail you. Otherwise I think it's not possible.

Comment: @Tofig Hasanov, yes I know that. But I can't install program to PC, because I don't know on which PC it will be opened, so that way is not appropriate for me

Comment: If you widen the solution from VBA to .NET then you can use Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO) which allows you to ship a C# .NET assembly attached to the workbook.

Comment: Does the document in discussion have (already) some VBA code, to make the one opening it to chose 'Enable Macros`, some ways can be imagined. Otherwise, it is hard to believe that the one opening it will do that... I mean, is it there a Form to be filled or something like this.

Comment: I wanted meaning to know if the document in discussion is `.doc` type, or `.docm`?

Comment: I think you may be better off writing to a log file on an internet accessible location vs e-mail as e-mail will require additionally outlook to be installed/configured on end users computer. But again, as it has been pointed out, if they don't "enable macros" then it won't work regardless.

Comment: @TofigHasanov it's 100% possible, it's effectiveness can be debated, but never underestimate end users! And security is about many layers, so perhaps this is one of many monitoring solutions, all of which combined make a robust solution.

Comment: @FruitDealer I'd love to see an example workbook output by that website! I've built FileServer honeypots before, but never file honeypots.

Comment: Probably it has a daemon which is checking which files are opened and what process are doing it. And when detect a file with a special extension (.doc) and/or magic numbers of the file, it sends an email.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a potential solution, however, there are still many variables at play that can prevent an email being sent. The below VBA is inserted in the `Document_Open` event handler. The method is sending an email through the Outlook application so the user who opens the file would need to have that installed too.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Document_Open()
    
    'only run when others open
    If Application.userName <> "My Name" Then
        
        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = False
            .DisplayAlerts = False
        End With
        
        Dim outApp As Object
        Dim outMail As Object
        Dim strBody As String
        Dim userName As String
        
        
        Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set outMail = outApp.createitem(0)
        
        userName = Application.userName
        strBody = userName & " has opened my file"
        
        With outMail
            .To = "myEmail@myDomain.com"
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "My file has been opened"
            .Body = strBody
            '.Display
            .Send
        End With
        
        Set outMail = Nothing
        Set outApp = Nothing
        
        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = True
            .DisplayAlerts = True
        End With
    End If
    
End Sub
```

The above runs smoothly but I end up with a security warning on my laptop (I am not sure if this is true across everyone else's). However, hopefully this gives you a starting point for you to tinker with to get the complete results.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is to write a VBA module within the word document that will fire on the onOpen event to create and send an email using the hosts default email program.  Or you could attempt to send an email using CDO or maybe even sendmail within word using VBA.  Note that if the person opening the document has macros disabled, the VBA module may not run.

Comment: In most cases this will prompt user to activate VBA, so any person who doesn't wish to notify you will just not allow script to run.

Comment: @TofigHasanov this comment is a repeat of your comment on OP